# gbp import-orig "revision not found" error

Tags: debian, packaging

I am trying to rebuild a Debian package using new upstream sources. I first do a `gbp import-dsc` on the Debian source package:

```
% gbp import-dsc heimdal_7.1.0+dfsg-13+deb9u2.dsc
gbp import-dsc heimdal_7.1.0+dfsg-13+deb9u2.dsc
gbp:info: No git repository found, creating one.
gbp:info: Tag upstream/7.1.0+dfsg not found, importing Upstream tarball
gbp:info: Version '7.1.0+dfsg-13+deb9u2' imported under '/srv/scratch/heimdal-work/heimdal'
```

No problem there. Next, I try to do an`import-orig` but get an error:

```
% cd heimdal
% gbp import-orig --verbose ../heimdal-7.5.0.tar.gz -u7.5.0
gbp:warning: Old style config section [git-import-orig] found please rename to [import-orig]
gbp:debug: ['git', 'rev-parse', '--show-cdup']
gbp:debug: ['git', 'rev-parse', '--is-bare-repository']
gbp:debug: ['git', 'rev-parse', '--git-dir']
gbp:debug: ['git', 'for-each-ref', '--format=%(refname:short)', 'refs/heads/']
gbp:debug: ['git', 'show-ref', 'refs/heads/upstream']
gbp:debug: ['git', 'status', '--porcelain']
gbp:debug: ['git', 'tag', '-l', 'upstream/7.5.0']
gbp:debug: tar ['-C', '../tmpiUAx3m', '-a', '-xf', '../heimdal-7.5.0.tar.gz'] []
gbp:debug: Unpacked '../heimdal-7.5.0.tar.gz' to '../tmpiUAx3m/heimdal-7.5.0'
gbp:info: Importing '../heimdal-7.5.0.tar.gz' to branch 'upstream'...
gbp:info: Source package is heimdal
gbp:info: Upstream version is 7.5.0
gbp:debug: ['git', 'rev-parse', '--quiet', '--verify', 'heimdal-7.5.0^{}']
gbp:error: Import of ../heimdal-7.5.0.tar.gz failed: revision 'heimdal-7.5.0^{}' not found
gbp:debug: rm ['-rf', '../tmpiUAx3m'] []
```

Why am I getting this error and how to work around it?

```
gbp:error: Import of ../heimdal_7.5.0.orig.tar.gz failed: revision 'heimdal-7.5.0^{}' not found
```

The version of gbp import-orig is 0.8.12.2.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of the following configuration directive in `debian/gbp.conf`:

```
upstream-vcs-tag=heimdal-%(version)s
```

This matches the upstream tags, but fails when you attempt to import the sources using `gbp`. To fix this, remove the above line.

You could save yourself a lot of time by using the packaged sources for version 7.5.0:

```
dget -x http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/h/heimdal/heimdal_7.5.0+dfsg-2.dsc
```

or

```
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/debian/heimdal.git
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to be on the `upstream` branch before running `gbp import-orig`. I am pretty sure that in earlier releases of `import-dsc` and `import-orig` that was not necessary.